# How can I inherit comments when using CREATE TABLE INHERITS

Tags: postgresql, create-table, inheritance

I have a table `basetemplate` created using:

```
CREATE TABLE basetemplate (
    time_of_creation timestamp with time zone,
);
```

Now I want to create `table1`, `table2` with different fields, but both containing `time_of_creation` field.
I tried using `CREATE TABLE LIKE` and `CREATE TABLE INHERITS`. 
Of this `CREATE TABLE INHERITS` seemed to better match my requirement, as I could create the new table with the new table's fields specified in the same query. But for the other method I would have to use `ALTER TABLE` query to add my new table's specific fields. 
`CREATE TABLE INHERITS` inherited the fields, its constraint; but not its comments.
My question is, whether this is the best way to fulfil my need and also is there a way to inherit comments also, when using `CREATE TABLE INHERITS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE INHERITS` is not suitable for just duplicating table definitions. The actual *data* of the tables are linked, so if that is not what you want, then do not use table inheritance, use `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE` or `CREATE TABLE ... OF TYPE`, then add fields with `ALTER TABLE` commands. If that's too cumbersome it might be a sign you should just be defining a new table, or perhaps using a composite type or a domain.

It seems like you're trying to apply OOP polymorphic inheritance to SQL. Not a great idea. In this case, your best bet is almost certainly just to live with repeating the common field. In more complex cases you can create a `DOMAIN`, or create a composite type with `CREATE TYPE`, but in this case that's unnecessary; just repeat the field in each table.

Here's what happens if you use `INHERITS` then insert a row into the base table:

```
regress=> CREATE TABLE basetemplate (
    time_of_creation timestamp with time zone
);
CREATE TABLE
regress=> CREATE TABLE table1 (col1 text) INHERITS (basetemplate);
CREATE TABLE
regress=> INSERT INTO table1(col1, time_of_creation) VALUES ('a', current_timestamp);
INSERT 0 1
regress=> SELECT * FROM table1 ;
       time_of_creation        | col1 
-------------------------------+------
 2012-11-08 16:23:35.645734+08 | a
(1 row)
```

fine so far, but now:

```
regress=> select * from basetemplate ;
       time_of_creation        
-------------------------------
 2012-11-08 16:23:35.645734+08
(1 row)
```

This probably isn't what you want.

It doesn't actually do any harm; there isn't any overhead to inserting rows into `table1` because of the inheritance. You'll find that it makes doing some management tasks more complicated later, though, and it'll complicate things like table partitioning. Overall I don't recommend using inheritance unless you need to.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE ... OF TYPE` is not usable for me, as I see that it is added in Postgresql 9.0 only. My production server still supports `8.3` version only.

Comment: I won't be doing any operations as such, on the `basetemplate` table, so is using inheritance feasible, or would it create any confusions or data collisions between two tables `table1` and `table2` that individually inherits from `basetemplate`?

Comment: @saji89 So long as you never create tables that inherit from `table1` or `table2` it should not create any data collision issues. I still think it's a terrible idea; it'll make schema maintenance and updates harder for one thing. Just repeat the required columns, or define a composite type and use that.

Comment: If it won;t be too much of an asking, could you tell me how to define a composite type, or point me to where I can find that.(Preferably add that info also to your answer). Thanks for your time.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html . Working with composite types can be hard from some client applications, it depends on the database driver you're using. If in doubt, test. You will also want to know about `DOMAIN`s: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html . These cause much fewer problems for client apps than composite types do. The safest option is almost certainly still "just repeat the columns in each table".

Comment: Thanks for those links. Seems too complex for such a simple requirement. I guess I would go with your advice to `repeat the columns in each table`.